# How to use google map tiles in my android app for offline use

Tags: android, google-maps, osmdroid

I am developing an Android app that show the user's location in Google Maps API 2. Now I want it so that the user can download a custom area or custom city map for offline use of the map. How can I implement this? I also use OSMDroid, but it is not loading the map, even online.

Comment: It's not possible with Android Google Maps V2 API...

Answer (score 0):

Read the [terms of use](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms):

> (b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not
>   pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i)
>   limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the
>   performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily
>   (and in no event for more than 30 calendar days), securely, and in a
>   manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service;
>   and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs
>   Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must
>   not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or
>   other local listings information.